# Is there one plugin/lib that allows to pick iOS files from both - Library&iCloud?

Tags: ios, cordova, media, picker, ionic4

Developing a music player in Ionic4, and found out that there is no plugin allowing to pick files from both - Library and iCloud. Is there a plugin/lib to make it?

This is for Ionic 4, it has a native plugin - iOSFilePicker that opens iCloud only, but not Library on iOS device!

Proofs:

https://github.com/TrueOleg/ionic3-test.git

https://github.com/TrueOleg/ionic4-test.git

I've made a deep investigation, searched for Ionic/Cordova plugins and tested them:

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin - iCloud only

https://github.com/WinGood/cordova-plugin-mediapicker/ - Library only

https://github.com/pabiagioli/icloud-filepicker-swift-ionic3 - iCloud only

https://github.com/lalit-mohan-negi/file-picker-ionic-ios/tree/master/src/ios - iCloud only

https://github.com/wdmchaft/DZDocumentsPickerController - iCloud only

https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-mediapicker - documentation says that it works with both, in fact - with Library only.

Thus, I use two pickers - iOSFilePicker for iCloud, cordova-plugin-mediapicker for Library.

Wondering is there a one picker for both?